# How to map Linux device nodes to USB devices?

Tags: linux, usb

If we have the list of enumerated USB devices, eg. the result of `lsusb`, and look at `/dev`, how can we tell which device nodes in `/dev` are made from a certain USB device?

I know there are several similar questions, but most of them have a more specific example and the accepted answers are specialised likewise.

Answer (score 1):

In `/sys/bus/usb` you find everything you need. It's a bit convoluted, but quite parseable.

E.g. (on my Ubuntu machine) the existance of the path `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/4-4\:1.0/host1/target1\:0\:0/1\:0\:0\:0/block/sdd` tells me, that block device `sdd` is at `usb-4-4:1.0`

This corresponds to

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
```

Comment: Ok. There are drivers listed that doesn't have a device attached. And how to be sure this list is exhaustive? And then, how to know that we look at block/ for a mass storage device, but at tty/ to find the device of an serial device? This seems quirky and error prone to me, as long there are no strong guarantees how those subpathes are named and which are there.

Comment: The device node itself is always a subdirectory of the device path, so this is very easily parseable with a shell script. We do it all the time on equipment where devices are pluggged in (or switched on) in unsupervised induistrial settings and have never had a problem.

Comment: Yes, but any hint how this subdirectory is named? To discern it from the varying other ones... tty, block, what else? How to always find the correct subdirectory?

Comment: You need to parse the tree depending on the driver, as every driver has a different structure accodring to the needs it has (there is no 1:1 relation between a physical USB device and the nodes in `/dev`). . E.g. for HID devices try `for f in /dev/input/* ; do find -L '/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid' -type d -maxdepth 5 -name $(basename "$f") ; done 2>/dev/null`